# Redux Thunk call another Thunk: Property 'type' is missing

Tags: typescript, redux, redux-thunk

I have a thunk that receives an id, and do some logic on a specific area of the store. Then I want to do some logic on a completely different area of the store.
To do this I can not trigger a regular action, as I wont have access to the store: I would need another thunk.

```
export const thunkOne = ({ id }) => async (dispatch: Dispatch, getState) => {
  const state = getState();

  await dispatch(thunkTwo({ id }));

  // ... do things with the state

  return;
};
```

Now `thunkTwo` is:

```
export const thunkOne = ({ id }) => (dispatch, getState) => {
  const { Bookmarks } = getState();
  // do some other logic

  return dispatch({
    type: ACTION_START,
    payload: {
      ...Bookmarks,
      id,
    },
  });
};
```

I'm getting this TypeScript error:

```
Argument of type '(dispatch: any, getState: any) => any' is not assignable to 
parameter of type 'AnyAction'.
Property 'type' is missing in type '(dispatch: any, getState: any) => any' but 
required in type 'AnyAction'.ts(2345)
index.d.ts(21, 3): 'type' is declared here.
```

Can't find the issue. Any help will be welcome!

Answer (score 2):

The error was in the type of the dispatch, as it should be  `ThunkDispatch<any, void, Action>`:

```
export const thunkOne = ({ id }) => async (dispatch: ThunkDispatch<any, void, Action>, getState) => {
  const state = getState();

  await dispatch(thunkTwo({ id }));

  // ... do things with the state

  return;
};
```

Comment: dispatch is synchronous - you can't await it ?!